# I Got Index was outside the bounds of the array , but i wanna do something with it?

Tags: c#, arrays

```
string[] filefile = dr["Path_XBRL"].ToString().Split('\\', '-');  

if (filefile[11] == null)
  { 
     string yes = "oke";
  }
```

i want to do with that value, but i got Index was outside the bounds of the array.what should i do then?

Comment: Always try to avoid hardcoded indexes. ;)

Comment: filefile element is always 0-10 but i want to do something if the element increase by 1 it means filefile[11] :)

Comment: I am speaking generally. First of all, hardcoded indexes are [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Secondly, you never know when array length/element order will change (especially, when you use third-party libraries).

Comment: so , when i want to do with that what should i do?

Comment: To avoid _magic numbers_ you should replace them with named constants. So if you _have to_ find eleventh element in array you'd better define constant: `const int NEEDEDINDEXTOASSIGNOKE = 11; //some awful name` and use one `filefile[NEEDEDINDEXTOASSIGNOKE]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string[] filefile = dr["Path_XBRL"].ToString().Split('\\', '-');
```

if you check this statement, you will see that the array contains less than 11 elements. If you want to check you may do the following;

```
if (filefile.Length >11 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(filefile[11]))
{ 
    string yes = "oke";
}
```

Comment: i still got Index was outside the bounds of the array , cause the filefile array is always [0]-[10] , but when i use  (filefile.Length >=11) only it works :)

Comment: hard to believe, because filefile.Length >=11 is evaluated first. if the test fails (that is, is false), the second condition (filefile[11] == null) is not being evaluated anymore.

Comment: @Adi yes the left side is evaluated first, and it is intended to be evaluated first; if index size is smaller than 11, no action is to be taken. if it is 11 and then check whether the the element at 11 is null or empty.

Comment: @Adi slight problem: array.length = count of the elements, however since arrays are 0-based, filefile[11] is element 12.

Comment: @daryal your checking can still throw an outofbounds exception when filefile.length == 11, please update.

Comment: @Destrictor Yup! it works (filefile.Length >11 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(filefile[11])) thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

*That* value doesn't exist (i.e. there's not a thing at that point in the array, indeed, the array doesn't span that length), that's the point. You might be overlooking that arrays are zero-index based, and, if the array parts are well defined, you could really want `filefile[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use `ElementAtOrDefault` to avoid out of index exception

```
if (filefile.ElementAtOrDefault(11) == null)
{}
```

Comment: `ElementAtOrDefault` doesn't return null if there was no element at index 11

Comment: I checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb494386.aspx) . it says it will return the default value if there was no element at that index

Comment: @AbZy: default value of reference type is null.